# Delete column if all entries after the header are a certain string

Tags: text-processing, command-line, files

I have a file of data that looks like this

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6
./.       ./.      ./.    ./.     ./.    ./.
./.       ./.      ./.    ./.     A/G    ./.
./.       ./.      ./.    ./.     ./.    ./.
A/A       A/A      A/G    ./.     ./.    ./.
```

And I'd like to remove all columns that contain only ./. to leave me with

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample5
  ./.     ./.     ./.     ./.
  ./.     ./.     ./.     A/G
  ./.     ./.     ./.     ./.
  A/A     A/A     A/G     ./.
```

I feel like the is a sed or awk command but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Correct, edited to match the title of the question.

Comment: how large is your file?

Comment: Quite small, usually only a few kb.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `awk`:**

```bsh
awk -v na="./." '
BEGIN{OFS=FS}
NR==FNR && NR>1 {
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!=na){s[i]=1}}
}
NR!=FNR {
  for(l in s){true} 
  for(i in s){if (i!=l){printf "%s"OFS,$i} else {printf "%s\n",$i}}
}
' file file
```

You might need to change `BEGIN{OFS=FS}` to `BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}` if your file is tab delimited.

**Explanation:**

- Go through file twice (`awk ... file file`)
- First time (`NR==FNR` and `NR>1` to exclude header) you verify that in your columns (`i`) is at least one value that is not `na="./."`, save column number in variable `s`.
- Second time (`NR!=FNR`), for every column saved in `s` print the column value. (First loop lets you know the last column to be printed (saved in variable `l`, so you can decide between printing `OFS` or `\n`.)

**Output:**

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample5
./. ./. ./. ./.
./. ./. ./. A/G
./. ./. ./. ./.
A/A A/A A/G ./.
```

If your file was tab-delimited, the output will be a bit nicer, if not, you can make it nice adding `|column -t`. It will then look like this:

```
Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample5
./.      ./.      ./.      ./.
./.      ./.      ./.      A/G
./.      ./.      ./.      ./.
A/A      A/A      A/G      ./.
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks for the BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} tip too, my data was indeed tab delimited.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane '
   push @{$AoA[$.-1]}, map { push @Cols2Keep, $_ if $. > 1 && $F[$_] ne "./." && !$seen{$_}++; $F[$_] } 0 .. $#F}
   {print join "\t", @{$AoA[$_]}[sort { $a <=> $b } @Cols2Keep] for 0 .. $#AoA
' file.tsv
```

**Results:**

```
Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample5
./.     ./.     ./.     ./.
./.     ./.     ./.     A/G
./.     ./.     ./.     ./.
A/A     A/A     A/G     ./.
```

**Working:**

- array of array @AoA, stores the file in the array indexed by the record number, `$.`. Since `$.` starts with a 1 whilst arrays in `Perl` are `0-indexed` we normalize `$.`
- array @Cols2keep stores the column number in which a `non ./.` element was found. We also don't want duplicates in it so we de-dup it by means of  hash `%seen` whose keys are these column numbers. Constraint is that we skip checking the first record.